# Save new data to excel using pandas without losing old data

Tags: python, pandas

I want to use **Pandas** to save new data to my Excel file which have many sheets. However, using `to_excel()` make all of my other sheets disappear. Is there any way to solve this problem?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pandas.ExcelWriter` to append files. Example code below. Output.xlsx is a file with a few Sheets and data present.

`````
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

path = r"output.xlsx"

x1 = np.random.randn(100, 10)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(x1)

x2 = np.random.randn(100, 2)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(x2)

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(path, mode='a', engine = 'openpyxl')
df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'NewSheet1')
df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'NewSheet2')
writer.save()
````
`````